# Bonjour/Zeroconf not working properly on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, dns, raspberry-pi, avahi

I have a raspberry pi (Raspian) running a nodejs http page. The pi has a hostname and uses Avahi to advertise it. I have the Bonjour service running on my Windows PC and I can access the page just fine.

However, on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop I can neither go to the web page nor ping the pi by hostname (DNS probe error in chrome), but I can do both of these things with the IP address. The same goes for my Android phone.

Do linux/android machines automatically block traffic on port 5353? Or is there something else going on here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!